# Combine rows SQL based on a sequence number

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

So say I have the following table

```
TABLE A
ID            Name              Value1          sequence_number
1             A                   4                    1
2             B                   5                    1
2             B                   6                    2
3             C                   7                    1
```

I basically want the table to look like this.. Whats the best way

```
TABLE B
ID            Name              Value1               Value2
1             A                   4                    
2             B                   5                    6
3             C                   7
```

I tried using case statments back to back but it generated this

```
TABLE C
ID            Name              Value1               Value2
1             A                   4                    
2             B                   5                    
2             B                                        6
3             C                   7
```

Any Thoughts?

Comment: learn PIVOT() for cross tab grids or write this in c#

Comment: In you table C, are the blanks NULL or empty strings?   While I agree about learning PIVOT, you can do something simpler if needed

Comment: they are empty strings

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Subquery with GROUP BY.

Check this code on SQLFiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31a42/11/0